# Need help with extension test class

Tags: unit-test, controller-extension

I need some major help writing a test class for my extension. I've work half the day with no luck. There's no use in posting what I've got as it isn't working. This is my first extension class. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

```
public with sharing class ext_GetAccountContacts 
{
public Task task;
public String objType = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('objType');
public String isPerson = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('isPerson');
public String acctIdParm = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('what_id');
public String cntIdParm = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('who_id');
public String selContact;
public String placeHolder {get;set;}

public ext_GetAccountContacts(ApexPages.StandardController stdController)
{
    task = (Task)stdController.getRecord();

    // Prefill fields with URL values
    task.subject = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('tsk5');
    task.status = ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().get('tsk12');

    // Set owner to current user
    task.ownerid = UserInfo.getUserId();

    // Set call date to today
    task.call_date__c = Date.Today();

    // Who and What
    if(acctIdParm != '' && acctIdParm != null) {task.whatid = acctIdParm;}
    if(cntIdParm != '' && cntIdParm != null) {task.whoid = cntIdParm;}

    // MSL Profile gets different record type
    if(UserInfo.getProfileId() != '00ei0000000kKHFAA2')
    {
        task.recordtypeid = '012i0000001I4Dc';
    }
    else
    {
        task.recordtypeid = '012f00000004Nv8';
    }
}

public List<SelectOption> getContacts()
{   
    if (objType != 'account' || isPerson == '1' || acctIdParm == null || acctIdParm == '')
    {
        return null;
    }

    List<String> personIds = new List<String>();
    List<Contact> allContacts = new List<Contact>();
    List<Contact> providerContacts = new List<Contact>();

    // ###################### GET BUSINESS CONTACTS FIRST ######################
    //
    allContacts =
    [
        SELECT id,Name,FirstName, LastName 
        FROM Contact 
        WHERE AccountId = : acctIdParm
    ];

    // ########## NOW GET PROVIDER CONTACTS AFFILIATED WITH BUSINESS ###########
    //
    List<Affiliation__c> affils =
    [
        SELECT Provider_Account__c // Formula field on Affiliation
        FROM Affiliation__c 
        WHERE Account__c = : acctIdParm
    ];

    // ########### SET LIST OF PERSON ACCT IDS FOR CONTACT QUERY ###############
    //
    for (Affiliation__c aff : affils)
    {
        personIds.add(aff.Provider_Account__c);
    }

    // ######################### QUERY CONTACT RECORDS #########################
    //
    if (personIds.size() > 0)
    {
        providerContacts =
        [
            SELECT Id, FirstName, LastName, Name
            FROM Contact
            WHERE AccountId IN : personIds
        ];
    }

    // ################# ADD PROVIDER CONTACTS TO ALLCONTACTS ##################
    //
    for (Contact cnt : providerContacts)
    {
        allContacts.add(cnt);
    }

    // ################## SET SELECTLIST OPTIONS WITH CONTACTS #################
    //
    List<SelectOption> options = new List<SelectOption>();

    options.add(new SelectOption('', '--None--'));

    for (Contact cnt : allContacts) 
    {
        options.add(new SelectOption(cnt.Id, cnt.Name));
    }

    return options;
}

public String getSelContact()
{
    return selContact;
}

// Set the selected Contact's ID as the whoid
public void setSelContact(String s)
{
    task.whoid = s;
}

public PageReference save()
{   
    // Set the activity date (due date) to equal call date.
    // This causes the activity history related list to be sorted by call date/time.
    task.ActivityDate = task.Call_Date__c;

    insert task;

    String prevPage = '/';

    If (acctIdParm != '' && acctIdParm != null)
    {
        prevPage = prevPage + acctIdParm;
    }
    else if (cntIdParm != '' && cntIdParm != null)
    {
        prevPage = prevPage + cntIdParm;
    }

    PageReference pg = new PageReference(prevPage);
    pg.setRedirect(true);
    return pg;
}
}
```

For giggles, this is what I have so far that's giving me an error: INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]. I currently have 49% coverage.

```
@isTest
private class test_ext_GetAccountContacts 
{
public static testMethod void myUnitTest() 
{   
    Pagereference pg = Page.newCall;
    Test.setCurrentPageReference(pg);

    Task tsk = new Task();

    insert tsk;

    ApexPages.Standardcontroller sc = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(tsk);

    ext_GetAccountContacts ext = new ext_GetAccountContacts(sc);

    Profile p = [SELECT Id FROM Profile WHERE Name = 'Medical Science Liaison']; 
    User u = new User
    (
        Alias = 'jblow', 
        Email='jblow@testorg.com', 
        EmailEncodingKey='UTF-8', 
        LastName='Blow', 
        LanguageLocaleKey='en_US', 
        LocaleSidKey='en_US', 
        ProfileId = p.Id, 
        TimeZoneSidKey='America/Los_Angeles', 
        UserName='jblow@testorg.com',
        Timezone_Offset__c = -5
    );

    System.runAs(u)
    {       
        Account acct = new Account
        (
            name = 'Test Account',
            Greer_ID__c = '55546'
        );

        // Add parameters to page URL
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('what_id', '001f000000CH3I2');
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('tsk5', 'Call');
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('tsk12', 'Completed');
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('isPerson', '0');
        ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('objType', 'account');

        List<selectOption> options = ext.getContacts();

        String cnts = ext.getSelContact();          
        ext.setSelContact(u.Id);
        ext.save();
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Based on the error message alone (I haven't gone through your code line by line), I'd say this is causing the error in ext_GetAccountContacts.save():

```
// Set the activity date (due date) to equal call date.
// This causes the activity history related list to be sorted by call date/time.
task.ActivityDate = task.Call_Date__c;

insert task;
```

> INVALID_FIELD_FOR_INSERT_UPDATE, Cannot specify Id in an insert call: [Id]

What the error is telling you is that you are trying to insert an account that has the Id field already defined. In that case you are really doing an **update**, not an **insert**.

If you don't care about the distinction Salesforce makes it easy for you be providing an `upsert` method.

Try changing your `insert task;` to `upsert task;` and you should get past the error.

If this isn't the case, can you provide some indication about which line it throwing the error (Best to mark it with a comment in the code sample as a line number is fairly meaningless in this context).

Comment: Thanks for your reply @Daniel. Turns out my what_id parm was causing the id issue. I worked through a couple more problems and eventually got the code below to work. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to work this one out. The hard coded what_id in my url parameter was causing an issue among other things. Here is the test that seem to do the trick.

```
@isTest
private class test_ext_GetAccountContacts 
{
public static testMethod void myUnitTest() 
{   
    Pagereference pg = Page.newCall;
    Test.setCurrentPageReference(pg);

    // Add parameters to page URL
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('tsk5', 'Call');
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('tsk12', 'Completed');
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('isPerson', '0');
    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('objType', 'account');

    Task tsk = new Task();

    Account acct = new Account
    (
        name = 'Test Account',
        Greer_ID__c = '55546'
    );

    insert acct;

    List<Account> insertedAcct = [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Greer_Id__c = '55546'];

    ApexPages.currentPage().getParameters().put('what_id', insertedAcct[0].Id);

    Contact cnt = new Contact
    (
        LastName = 'Test Contact',
        AccountId = insertedAcct[0].Id
    );

    insert cnt;

    List<Contact> insertedCnt = [SELECT Id FROM Contact WHERE LastName = 'Test Contact'];

    ApexPages.Standardcontroller sc = new ApexPages.Standardcontroller(tsk);

    ext_GetAccountContacts ext = new ext_GetAccountContacts(sc); 

    // Call methods
    ext.getContacts();              
    ext.setSelContact(cntOption);
    ext.save();
}
}
```